# How to hide days outside of the current month in Kendo Scheduler ? (Kendo UI Angular)

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

How to hide dates outside of the current month in month view of year in Kendo UI Angular Scheduler?
[Please Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shp5k.png)